# macOS keyboard layout not working on Linux trough barrier on Gnome

Tags: terminal, keyboard

My problem is the same as [MacOS keyboard layout not working on linux trough barrier(synergy)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685572/macos-keyboard-layout-not-working-on-linux-trough-barriersynergy/741036#741036)

My workspace contains Kali Linux installed on a DELL Latitude E54670 and a macOS Monterey 12.6.1 on a MacBook Air 2015.

The server is the macOS and the client is the Kali, I use SSL and it works as well for most.

My issue is a little bit complicated, when I type <kbd>></kbd>, <kbd>{</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd> on my Mac it doesn't work on Kali.

I've tried to solve my problem by changing the keyboard layout to Macintosh on my Kali but it doesn't work; I've tried to add

```
keystroke(<) = keystroke(<,*)
```

to my barrier.conf file and it works, but when I add

```
keystroke(<) = keystroke(<,*)
keystroke(>) = keystroke(>,*)
```

it's broken

Do you have a solution?

PS: all this key works on mac in all software (terminal too)

Comment: Do those keys work properly on your Mac?

Comment: yes, as well ! (i add some chars)

Comment: If you open Terminal, do they work there as well?

Comment: edited ! (i add some chars)